# Put image in PopOver header

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

How to put an image in `PopOver` header instead of text?

```
PopOver popover = new PopOver(); 
popover.setTitle("Controls");
```

I want to set an image not a text.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a `ImageView` as [`contentNode`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/PopOver.html#contentNodeProperty)

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png");
PopOver popOver = new PopOver();
popOver.setContentNode(imageView);
```

If you want a header instead, you could simply use a `VBox` or a `BorderPane` or a similar suitable layout as `contentNode`...

Comment: @BoudjemaaBaali I've no idea what went wrong in your code, but the only 2 lines I added to sucessfully show the `PopOver` were `popOver.setArrowLocation(PopOver.ArrowLocation.LEFT_TOP);popOver.show(btn);` where `btn` is the button the `PopOver` is shown for. Note that it may take some time to download the image from the web, but you could also use an url to a image on your harddrive or some resource in a jar file...

Comment: thank you it's work ! ,but it's not what i was looking for, if i want to set string as title for the PopOver i will use popover.setTitle(""); but i want to use image instead of string ,they use label for the title but   i don't now how to access this label to put image as backgrond for it ?